# Cypress mouse event not working on map based applications (canvas)

Tags: cypress

I have a map-based application and hovering the mouse anywhere on the map, will show me the latitude and longitude value along with coordinates as in the picture.

[image]

I am trying to automate that and for some strange reason, the mouse events are not recognized if I use cypress.

Below is my code on a much similar application.

```
context('map', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('https://www.google.com/maps/')
    })

it('mouse hover /click on map', () => {
    cy.contains('I agree').click(); 
    //cy.contains('Jeg accepterer').click();
    cy.contains('COVID-19', { timeout: 30000 }).should('be.visible')
    //Hovering mouse or manual click gives the right values, 
    //  so added click also in above code
    cy.get('.widget-scene-canvas').click(80, 90)
    //.realClick();
 });

//Tried the following combinations and no luck: 
    // cy.get('.grid-container').eq(0).contains('Lat')
    // .invoke('trigger', 'mouseout')
    // .invoke('trigger', 'mouseenter')
    // .invoke('trigger', 'mouseleave')
    // .invoke('trigger', 'mouseover')
    // .trigger('mouseenter')
    // .trigger('onmouseover')
    // .trigger('mousedown', { force: true, which: 1 })
    // .trigger('mousemove', { force: true, clientX: 400, clientY: 500 })
    // .trigger('mouseup', { force: true })
    // .realHover()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `https://www.google.com/maps/` I don't see the lat-long `.grid-container` you mention, but you can get lat-long from the map with a right-click.

The basic problem is that google maps loads some additional code after initial display. You can see it in the Cypress log as `(xhr)` and clicking these logs shows the code in dev console.

The simplest way to get lat-long from `https://www.google.com/maps` is to arbitrarily wait, but it's flaky depending on network speed.

```js
cy.visit('https://www.google.com/maps/place/copenhagen')
cy.get('body').click()   // remove any covering layers, e.g covid messages

cy.wait(7000)  // wait for whatever code is required to display lat-long

cy.get('canvas').rightclick('center')  // open context menu

cy.contains("Directions from here")  // this text is visible
  .parents('ul')                     // parent menu
  .children().eq(0)                  // first item is lat-long
  .invoke('text')
  .should('contain', '55.67119, 12.45374')   // passes
```

To get rid of the arbitrary wait there are a couple of strategies

- use an intercept and wait until all (xhr) stop after say 2 seconds (still a bit arbitrary)
- identify which (xhr) contains the code needed to perform the click (for your map) or right-click (for google maps), then wait on an intercept for that (xhr)

---

The problem might be that the lat-lon displayed is a child of the canvas.

In google maps, it's a child of DOM so it can easily be queried by Cypress.

But when you inspect the `<canvas>` element in dev tools, it has no children to query, although clearly there are children displayed on the screen.

Comment: Thank you @Mihi, I do not have right click option on my application like we have in google maps but maps is the similar most application, please see if you can come up with a solution without right clicking

Comment: `rightclick` is just what works for google maps. Without a more comparable example, I can't really suggest much more than what you have already tried.

Comment: The problem might be that the lat-lon displayed is a child of the canvas. In google maps, it's a child of DOM so it can easily be queried by Cypress. But when you inspect the `<canvas>` element in dev tools, it has no children to query, although clearly there are children displayed on the screen.